# When using a custom decorator on a get accessor, why do I get an error about an 'Invalid property descriptor'?

Tags: angular, typescript, getter

For some reason when I use a decorator on a get accessor (as shown below), I pass compilation, but always end up with a runtime error message saying:

**Uncaught TypeError: Invalid property descriptor. Cannot both specify accessors and a value or writable attribute**

Why does this happen and how can I overcome it?  To note: I am only using a getter and not a setter.

Example Code:

```
class ThingBox {
    private things = [1,2,3,4,5]

    @MyDecorator
    get totalTings(): number { return this.things.length }
}
```

[Playground Link Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#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-F25CciA+UC+SEjMkSkaU-aySiWiGRayAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set a `get` method and `value` in the descriptor, but this is invalid (you can have accessors or value, not both). In your case, you need to patch the `get` method inside of the decorator instead of `value.`

Comment: Inside of the decorator function, we cannot use `descriptor.value` for an accessor. Instead we use `descriptor.get` or `.set`. I was able to make my decorator work with both methods and get accessors by changing the `descriptor.value` line to: `descriptor[descriptor.get ? 'get' : 'value'] `